# Ignoring swagger endpoints which are not in Golang router

Tags: go, swagger

I am using swagger to generate documentation of REST APIs in Golang. I have multiple micro-services in my project. Some of the APIs are common to all the services so I have kept them  common. So my Golang code looks like this:

```
import othercontroller "github.com/controllerv2"
func Controller() {
    ...

    // version V1 gpd
    router.HandleFunc(utils.BasePath+"/entity", c.handleCreate).Methods(http.MethodPost)
    router.HandleFunc(utils.BasePath+"/entity/{id}", c.handleDelete).Methods(http.MethodDelete)

    othercontroller.AttachStatRoutes(utils.BasePath, router)
    router.Serve()
}
```

APIs in "othercontroller" looks something like this:

```
func AttachStatRoutes(basepath string, router Router) {
    router.HandleFunc(basepath+"/stats", getStatsHandler).Methods("GET")
}

func AttachHealthRoutes(basepath string, router Router) {
    router.HandleFunc(basepath+"/health", getHealthHandler).Methods("GET")
}
```

Swagger definition for getStatsHandler API looks like this

```
// swagger:operation GET /stats  Stat
//
//
// ---
// produces:
// - application/json
// parameters:
// - name: ID
//   in: query
//   description: stats ID
//   required: false
//   type: string
// responses:
//   '200':
//     description: Stats response
//     schema:
//       "$ref": "#/definitions/StatsResponse"
//   '400':
//     description: Bad Request
//   '403':
//     description: Forbidden, you are not authorized
//   '500':
//     description: Error occurred while processing the request

func getStatsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // some logic here
}
```

"getHealthHandler" API of AttachHealthRoutes() function is also in the same package and has similar swagger UI definition.

Now when I generate the swagger, I am also getting swagger UI for APIs which are in AttachHealthRoutes() function but I am not attaching it to the router.

So what I need is, swagger should only show me UI for APIs which are attached to routers.
What I am assuming is, I am getting the swagger for API of AttachHealthRoutes() becasue getHealthHandler is in the same package as that of getStatHandler.

Note that I can not keep them in different packages.

Can anyone tell me how can I get rid of getHealthHandler API from swagger UI?

Comment: What are you using to generate the swagger? Perhaps there are options in there to exclude routes?

Comment: I am using this in my controller to generate swagger. It is executed when build is running.
//go:generate swagger generate spec -m -o ./swagger.json

Answer (score 1):

@jmoney thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was searching for the solution everywhere else but not where the swagger was getting generated.
There are indeed options to exclude options. Found them here:

https://goswagger.io/generate/spec.html

Following command worked for me:

```
//go:generate swagger generate spec -m -o ./swagger.json -x, --exclude-tag=Health
```

Comment: Glad that helped and thanks for posting your solution here to help others in the future!